# kill-word / forward-word should stop at newline

Tags: emacs

I find it rather annoying that kill-word and forward-word treat newline character as whitespace and e.g. kill everything up to the end of the word in the next line. I would like it to stop at the end of the line instead.

I tried modifying the syntax table to include newline character into the word definition as follows:

> (modify-syntax-entry ?\n "w")

This gives the desired effect, but needs to be specified separately for every syntax table.

Is there a way to achieve this effect globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first off I would strongly recommend getting used to the idea of treating newlines as whitespace for the most part.  Emacs generally does this consistently and trying to buck such a trend might be a never-ending battle.

Secondly I agree with the answer given by Stefan in that messing with the syntax table, or re-defining `forward-word` itself, will cause you nothing but trouble and grief.

If you really want the behaviour you describe for `M-d` and `M-f` then perhaps it would be best to define a new set of functions that have this desired behaviour, and to which you can bind the `M-d` and `M-f` keys to.

Indeed this would be the traditional way to change the default behaviour of some core functionality in any emacs.

Maybe something like this?  (barely tested)

```
(defun forward-word-stop-eol (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((start (point)))
    (save-restriction
      (save-excursion
        (move-end-of-line 1)
        (narrow-to-region start (point)))
      (forward-word arg))))

(defun kill-to-end-of-word-or-line (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (kill-region (point) (progn (forward-word-stop-eol arg) (point))))

(global-set-key "\ef" forward-word-stop-eol)
(global-set-key "\ek" kill-to-end-of-word-or-line)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I'm still yet to figure out what the most efficient way of navigating code/text is for me, but that certainly provides a great starting point.

Comment: this is pretty good, I adapted to a bacwkard-will-word-stop-eol. I would just like to delete the newline if I hit it once more time. bascially behavior of the backward-kill-word but making 'one stop' on the newline

Answer (score 1):

Changing the syntax of the `?\n` character will get you quickly into trouble in all kinds of modes.  Instead, you want to change the way things like `forward-word` behave when called interactively (note that changing the behavior of the function `forward-word` can also lead to trouble because it is often used in things like indentation code).  You might like to take a look at how `subword-mode` works for an example of how this can be done.

Comment: I checked the subword-mode code and it's also a great source of information. If I decide for a more "complex" navigation functionality, I will certainly use subword as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I used `with-syntax-table` to temporarily (and globally) modify the syntax table.

E.g., I used it with `syntax-subword` mode:

```
(defadvice syntax-subword-forward (around testing activate)
  (with-syntax-table (copy-syntax-table (syntax-table))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">")
    ad-do-it))
```