# Emacs Ctrl+Backspace kills too much

Tags: windows, emacs

Using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.2.9200) on Windows 8.1

I've noticed that C-DEL (Ctrl+Backspace) eats every newline tell it can eat a full word.

```
test.. \n
\n
\n<cursor>
```

becomes an empty file.

Is there a way to have it only eat until a full word or until a newline (like in sublime)?

or alternative to my habit from other text editors?

Comment: [kill-word stops at newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896402/kill-word-forward-word-should-stop-at-newline) would help.  But I don't think just getting used to it is better :)

Comment: I'm working on `lawlist-kill-word` in this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958397/emacs-delete-whitespaces-or-a-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword

This stops at the space after the second dot, but kills all the newlines.  In general, it makes word operations more fine-grained.