# IntelliJ make whitespace+newline same word

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax, keyboard-shortcuts, whitespace

When deleting words (ctrl+backspace or ctrl+delete) in IntelliJ it treats whitespace as a word until it hits a newline character. I want to treat every sequence of space/tab and newline[sequences] as one word.

Essentially this is the reverse problem of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896402/kill-word-forward-word-should-stop-at-newline) in IntelliJ.

Sadly i did not find any setting to do that so far.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a "Hungry Backspace" action.

Yet there exists no "Hungry Delete" out of the box.

And it does not work for non-whitespace words.